# Some PDF attachments do not open when added using PyPDF4. How to fix this?

Tags: python, pdf, attachment, pypdf4

I am using PyPDF4 to add file attachments to a base PDF. The final PDF file opens and has all attachment PDFs attached but some of them do not open when double-clicked.

Could you advise on why this happens and what's the workaround for the same? The code as below. All files 1.pdf to 9.pdf open through attachments but 11.pdf does not. The file however opens from the folder.

```
#----addAttachment function of PyPDF4 is modified to add instead of replacing---#
import os
import PyPDF4
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF4.generic import DecodedStreamObject, NameObject, DictionaryObject, createStringObject, ArrayObject

def appendAttachment(myPdfFileWriterObj, fname, fdata):
    #The entry for file
    file_entry = DecodedStreamObject()
    file_entry.setData(fdata)
    file_entry.update({NameObject("/Type") : NameObject("/EmbeddedFile")})

    #The Filespec entry
    efEntry = DictionaryObject()
    efEntry.update({NameObject("/F") : file_entry})

    filespec = DictionaryObject()
    filespec.update({NameObject("/Type") : NameObject("/Filespec"), NameObject("/F") : createStringObject(fname), NameObject("/EF") : efEntry})

    if "/Names" not in myPdfFileWriterObj._root_object.keys():
        # No files attached yet. Create the entry for the root, as it needs a reference to the Filespec
        embeddedFilesNamesDictionary = DictionaryObject()
        embeddedFilesNamesDictionary.update({NameObject("/Names"): ArrayObject([createStringObject(fname), filespec])})

        embeddedFilesDictionary = DictionaryObject()
        embeddedFilesDictionary.update({NameObject("/EmbeddedFiles"): embeddedFilesNamesDictionary})
        myPdfFileWriterObj._root_object.update({NameObject("/Names"): embeddedFilesDictionary})
    else:
        # There are files already attached. Append the new file.
        myPdfFileWriterObj._root_object["/Names"]["/EmbeddedFiles"]["/Names"].append(createStringObject(fname))
        myPdfFileWriterObj._root_object["/Names"]["/EmbeddedFiles"]["/Names"].append(filespec)

pdf_file = 'Contents.pdf'
attachment_file = ['1.pdf','2.pdf','3.pdf','4.pdf','5.pdf','6.pdf','7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf', '11.pdf']


pdf_reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(open(pdf_file,'rb'))
pdf_writer = PyPDF4.PdfFileWriter()

pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(0))
for i in range(len(attachment_file)):
    with open(attachment_file[i],'rb') as f:
        appendAttachment(pdf_writer,attachment_file[i],f.read())
        f.close()
    with open('CalBook.pdf','wb') as f:
        pdf_writer.write(f)
```

Comment: Something I observed while trying out is that if I name a file as 'A.pdf' and another as 'AA.pdf', then 'AA.pdf' does not open from attachments. Similarly I tried for 'C.pdf' and 'CCC.pdf'. Same outcome. It seems this issue has something to do with the name of file when it begins with same character. I believe, assuming this as true, only 26 files can be guaranteed to open if a particular naming system is followed. I could be wrong.

Comment: What program are you opening the PDF in? Some PDF readers refuse to open an attachment if they think it might be a security threat, so perhaps something is triggering that check falsely? Can you try opening in another PDF reader which knows about attachments? If that fails too, then it's probably a PyPDF problem. What happens with `cpdf -list-attachments file.pdf`. What about `cpdf -dump-attachments file.pdf -o .`?

Comment: Use pypdf. PyPDF4 is not actively developed